# DHCP server does not work with 2 router

Tags: networking, cisco

i have problem on packet tracer  when i try to setup DHCP server with 2 different network and 2 router..

my setup is Two 2811 router, Two 2960 switch , One DHCP server and 4 PCs.

in Router 1 I have the DHCP server and 1 PC

and this the configuration for the router 1

[image: configuration for the router 1]

and this the configuration for the router 2

[image: configuration for the router 2]

and this is my diagram

[image: diagram]

if I remove the router number 2 "in the left side" everything works good!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a misconfiguration on the link between the 2 routers.
On the "left" router1 fa0/0 has an ip address in the 192.168.99.0/24 range.

On the right router0 fa0/1 has an ip in the 192.168.3.0/24 range. Thus both routers can not communicate with eachother.

You need a seperate subnet between the 2 to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

As Goez mentioned in his answer, you have the router to router link interfaces misconfigured. You need to assign an ip address in a different subnet to these interfaces. Think of 192.168.3.0 as the "inside" network on Router 1 and 192.168.99.0 as the "inside" network on Router 0. The router to router link is the "outside" network. You need to configure the "outside" network on each router with a different subnet and ip addresses than the "inside" networks. The "outside" interfaces on each router should belong to the same subnet.

As an example, you could configure the "outside" interface on Router 0 with the ip address 10.0.0.1/8 and the "outside" interface on Router 1 with the ip address 10.0.0.2/8, or 192.168.1.1/24 and 192.168.1.2/24, etc., etc.

You could use any ip addresses on those interfaces you choose just so long as both interfaces have ip addresses in the same subnet.